# Accessing weight data via the Google Fit REST API

Tags: google-fit

For the last 6 months I've been entering my weight into Google Fit, I now want to get my data out.

Accessing the Google Fit REST API hasn't been an issue.  Finding my weight data amongst the all the accessible data has stumped me however.

Any pointers gratefully appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately not :-(

Answer (score 12):

I can get all weight data
I found API request for all weight data
https://www.googleapis.com/fitness/v1/users/me/dataSources/derived:com.google.weight:com.google.android.gms:merge_weight/datasets/0-1443194884000000000

Last set is Start time and end time (in nanoseconds). Let me know if you have issue for weight Data. May be this query will help you.